# Error While adding reference to lpssl.dll in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, payment-gateway, firstdata

One of my website is in framework 1.1 and its using first data payment gateway. we are migrating our servers and after migration purchase functionality has stopped working. now i am creating a test application with the same code of one page "the final purchase code" so that i could recognize the error. on the following code it is asking about the reference to "lpssl" dll, when i trying to add reference of this dll its giving me the following error:
please help me how can i do it.
[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lpssl.dll is not a com component so you can't add its reference to your project.

For first data gatway integration you need to put lpssl.dll in you path (bin) folder.

For more details about first data gatway integration please visit blow link

http://adventuresindotnet.blogspot.in/2012/02/linkpointtransactiondll.html

You can also contact to first data support team.

I hope it will help you .